# Join table2 where table1 result doesn't match

Tags: mysql, join

I have a small table1 with paths like `foo/bar`.

I have a large table2 with full urls like `https://www.google.com/foo/bar/`.

I want to select the table1 paths, that don't exist in full urls in table2.

I tried a JOIN with REGEXP but the query is very slow and I may have chosen the wrong join:

```
SELECT t1.path
FROM table1 AS t1
RIGHT JOIN `table2` AS  t2
        ON ( REPLACE(t1.path, '/', '\\/') REGEXP ".+" + t2.url + ".*" )
WHERE t1.path != ""
ORDER BY t1.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

A subquery with NOT IN might help, but I'm not sure how to use the result path of the first query:

```
SELECT path
FROM `table1`
WHERE path != ""
    NOT IN (
            SELECT url FROM `table2` WHERE url LIKE "%" + [path of query 1] + "%"
           )
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You can't.  Your data is not suitable for a fast `join`.

Comment: So separate queries or each result of the paths?

Comment: . . MySQL does not provide efficient support for partial string matches as join conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the subquery with `LIKE` like this

```
SELECT path
FROM `table1`
WHERE TRIM(path) <> ''
    AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT url FROM `table2` WHERE url LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.path, '%')
           )
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But as Gordon Linoff already pointed out, your data is not suitable for a fast join. This query will be slow, because `LIKE` operations with strings are very expensive.

Comment: Thanks. Takes 11 seconds for 20k rows in table1 and 250k rows in table2. Correction: `LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.path, '%')`